# How to view xlsx file to new tab in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx

How to view excel file (xlsx) type in new tab after download from the server using angular(typescript)

Just like to view pdf or txt files I have write code like below and its working fine but its not working for excel type files.

```
       if(filename.split('.').pop() == 'pdf') {
            var FileAsBlob = new Blob(binaryData, { type: "application/pdf" });
    
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(FileAsBlob);
            var redirectWindow = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
            redirectWindow.location;
          //Other browsers\
          }
          else{
            var blob = new Blob(binaryData, { type: filename.split('.').pop() });
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var redirectWindow = window.open(downloadLink.href,'_blank');
            redirectWindow.location;
          }
```

Anyone please ! Help me with viewing xlsx file to new tab.

Comment: I am not sure that chrome is able to display an .xlsx file as Excel or other app would do. You could probably display it using an other type but the render would probably be bad/useless. You should just make the browser download the file and then chrome will automatically open the excel file using the right app when the user clicks on the file.